# Can I convert expired azure subscription to "pay-as-you-go" subscription with a free F1 plan?

Tags: azure, subscription

I am not sure if I understand how this works and if I could accidentally be charged if I do this?
I want to play around with Azure just for myself, deploy a web app, learn how it works.
I have an old Visual Studio subscription that I got years ago from a company I used to work at.
This subscription is old and disabled now, expired. I have an option to convert it into pay-as-you-go subscription. When I try to do that, it is asking for my credit card. I don't want to use any paid services, I just want to play with a basic free service plan (I believe it is called F1).
If I provide my credit card and convert that subscription to "pay-as-you-go", it is not going to charge me right away for something? I am not very familiar how this works. Thank you.

Comment: Please open a billing support request with Azure Support. They’ll be able to guide you properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the pay as you go plan and it required a credit card to subscribe.

It is possible to use the Azure subscription without paying as long as you use the F1 (Free) service plan for any of the services you use.

Once you start using the Basic, Standard or Premium plans, then you will be billed monthly to those services, and almost all those paid plan costs accumulate hourly.

It is possible to use the non-free services as well and use almost nothing as long as you remove the resources soon after use. As with any service, please do check the pricing to ensure you don't use a service longer than is needed.